# Proof that group homomorphisms are associative

Tags: group-theory, functions, group-homomorphism, function-and-relation-composition

Let $\varphi:G\to H$ and $\psi: H\to I$ and $\chi:I\to J$ be homomorphisms of the groups $G,H,I,J$.  I want to prove that homomorphisms are associative, that is to say $\varphi\circ (\psi\circ \chi) = (\varphi\circ\psi)\circ \chi$.  My proof is as follows:

All homomorphisms are functions.  All functions are associative.  Therefore all homomorphisms are associative.

However, my tutor claimed that this was a weird and over-complicated proof, and that homomorphisms are just associative by definition (and that most mathematicians would be "boggled at the weird gyrations" that I made in my proof).  I wanted to see if I have some kind of profoundly weird or mistaken understanding here.  I claimed that homomorphisms are not defined to be associative, as I don't see that in the Wikipedia article or any textbook.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism)

(Of course my proof relies on the principle that all functions are associative, which I believe for the purpose of this proof I can assume.)

Comment: You are right.  There is nothing to this, and nothing special about homs.  Function composition is associative.

Comment: (Most "advanced" mathematicians would consider the question trivial, but for a beginning learner your argument is the correct one, and exactly the way you should be thinking about it.)

Comment: That's the shortest "over-complicated" proof I've ever seen.

Comment: @J.G. I was kinda thinking the same thing.  Guy made me feel pretty stupid even while I was pretty sure he was wrong. (He was giving me a lot of eye rolls and disgusted looks, and repeatedly said I'm making things harder than they have to be, on this and other problems.)  But on the other hand, his proof was shorter.  "It's just by definition."

Comment: I would personally advise you to reconsider working with this tutor. This reaction is just ridiculous.

Comment: @Addem I suspect that what the tutor might actually have been confused by is your specific language. It is not correct to say that "functions are associative"; the correct phrasing is that "the composition of functions is associative". The tutor's reaction still seems unwarranted, of course

Comment: @BenGrossmann Very fair point.

Comment: Agreeing with @CaptainLama